# Ubuntu 18.04 VirtualBox black screen after login

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, login, login-screen

I've been running Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox for 5 months now, with no problems.

Today, I've encountered a quite annoying problem, to be honest. After I log in, the screen goes black with no reaction from mouse or keyboard input.

After a while though, the login screen reappears, but if I log in again the same thing happens, over and over again. I've already increased my Video memory in settings but that doesn't help.

Also, I wonder why this is happening now, although it never happened in the previous 5 months. Note that I only use this virtual machine for school stuff.

Answer (score 0):

When using VirtualBox with Ubuntu 18.04 I have to leave full screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) and reduce VirtualBox display windows by dragging it to a lower size for Ubutnu system to boot an activate view on login window. Playing with screen size often allows me to overcome unresponsive cases.

Once login is complete I use fullscreen again and it works. I have a dual screen setup on a laptop under windows 7 with  older VirtualBox 5.2.20, this is behaving this way for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (black screen after login) that I fixed by :

- Downloading and installing the lastest version of VirtualBox from Oracle website
- Configuring the graphic controler to VBoxVGA and increasing memory video to 96 Mo.

I hope this will help someome.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me after updating latest version of "Xubuntu" as part of The Odin Project.
*for Window users*>I am using a Windows 10 OS and if you click the black screen, simply press  FN+F8 and you will see the cursor re-appear (no need to reboot)

1. The issue happened when I clicked the black screen that would normally boot up and have the GUI we are used to seeing.
2. I clicked View>Virtual Screen1>then Scale to 100% (click OK for the warning about Host+Ctrl)
   3.Then I closed the window by clicking the top-right X in the window
3. IMPORTATNT, DO NOT 'Save the machine state' >this was causing me to get the loop over and over.
4. Then restart and it SHOULD start anew.